# Core data related objects being removed

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm currently stuck with a weird problem with core data. The app I'm writing downloads a bunch of data from the server, which is translated into core data objects and stored. The device can also create new objects and upload them to the server. One of these objects is a Document which is essentially a representation of a file.

The model for this is `MPDocument`. A document can also be linked to an `MPPlace` model, and an `MPUser` model (users create documents, and documents belong to places).

I'm having no problem downloading the objects from the server, and all relationships are being created and assigned correctly. The problem lies when I try to create a new document on the device itself. The document gets created, and I set all of the relationships, the document gets uploaded and everything seems fine. But when I check the database through a core-data viewer tool, all of the document objects have no value for the place relationship. This happens to all the existing documents, not just the new one. I really can't figure out what's going on!

I'm creating the document like so :

```
   MPUser *current = [MPUser currentUser];
   MPDocument *doc = [[MPDocument alloc] init];
          doc.name = @"App Upload";
     doc.local_url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]];
doc.local_url_type = @(MPDocumentUrlTypeAsset);
          doc.user = current;

[current addCreatedDocumentsObject:doc];
[doc setValue:self.place forKey:@"place"];
[self.place addDocumentsObject:doc];
```

I then have a document uploader which handles all uploading :

```
MPDocumentUploader *uploader = [[MPDocumentUploader alloc] initWithDocument:doc];
    uploader.requestDelegate = self;
       uploader.successBlock = ^(MPDocumentUploader *uploader, MPDocument *doc) {
           NSLog(@"Got doc = %@", doc);
       };
[uploader upload];
```

When the success block is called, the document object DOES have the place relationship set. So even once the upload has finished, the place is set, so I'm really confused now as to where the relationships are being completely cleared.

The document uploader looks something like this :

```
- (void) upload
{
    .... retrieve the local file and turn into NSData. This is fine
    MPRequest *request = [MPRequest requestWithURL:_url];
    [MPUser signRequest:request];
    [request setDelegate:_requestDelegate];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request mountDocumentUploader:self];

    [request submit:^(MPResponse *resp, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *)[resp paramForKey:@"data"];
            if (data) {
                NSLog(@"Document = %@", _document);
                _document.url = [data objectForKey:@"url"];
                _document.objID = [data objectForKey:@"id"];
                [_document saveLocally];
            }

            if (_successBlock) {
                _successBlock(self, _document);
            }
        } else {
            if (_failBlock) {
                _failBlock(self, error);
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

The `MPRequest` class handles all the actual uploading and server requests, but doesn't actually touch the MPDocument object.

I can't figure out what's going on or why it's clearing out the relationships. Please can someone help!?

**Update**

I've played around, and found that the error occurs when the submit block is called. Commenting out

```
_document.url = [data objectForKey:@"url"];
_document.objID = [data objectForKey:@"id"];
[_document saveLocally];
```

works as it is meant to, but now those values obviously aren't set. Adding either of those lines back in 1 at a time in isolation still causes the problem, so it seems that simply editing it at all is breaking it. Still no clue why though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok well I'm not entirely sure what happened or why, but between fiddling with the code, cleaning the project, and restarting my laptop, it seems to have fixed itself so not a clue what the issue was but it currently seems to be ok. Very confused :S